# SSD TRIM Support in Snow Leopard

Tags: mac-osx, ssd, osx-snow-leopard, trim

Does Mac OS X Snow Leopard *officially* support SSD TRIM yet? If not, is there an expected availability? Also, is there a brand of SSD that is most compatible with a late-2009 Mac Pro?

Answer (score 2):

TRIM is officially support with the latest build of 10.6 ***on Apple supplied SSDs only***, i.e. not on an after-market SSD.

Comment: Is there a link to a support article for this?

Comment: There was lots of stuff about it on macnn and macrumors when the last Air's came out.

Comment: http://www.groths.org/?p=308.  That said, it made performance worse on my garbage-collection enabled SSD.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM_%28SSD_command%29#Operating_system_and_SSD_support), [referencing this hack](http://www.hardmac.com/news/2011/03/27/the-universal-solution-to-activate-trim):

> TRIM can be unofficially enabled on Mac OS X Snow Leopard by modifying extensions. Since February 2011 MacBook Pro models that ship with Intel SSDs are supported by Apple and feature TRIM support. Reinstalling the OS disables TRIM by default. It can be re-enabled by 3rd party software. By modifying extensions TRIM feature can be patched to support third-party SSDs and installed on other Macs

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for *official* support from Apple. I've modified my question to reflect this. That hack looks very useful though!

Answer (score 0):

As stated, only Apple SSDs are supported.

However, to work around this restriction, you just need to zero out all instances of `APPLE SSD` inside the binary `IOAHCIBlockStorage`.

A command line solution is

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions/IOAHCIFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOAHCIBlockStorage.kext/Contents/MacOS/
sudo cp -pX IOAHCIBlockStorage ~IOAHCIBlockStorage
sudo perl -pi -e 's|\x41\x50\x50\x4c\x45\x20\x53\x53\x44|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00|g' IOAHCIBlockStorage
sudo rm /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup/Extensions.mkext
sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions/
```

Source: [Keeping TRIM on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 Update](https://mackonsti.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/keeping-trim-on-10-6-8-update/)

This worked perfectly on a Penryn 17" Macbook Pro with a WD Green 240 GB SSD, running OS X 10.6.8.

As an aside, I found that **Trim Enabler 2.2**, as advocated by this article, [WORKING DOWNLOAD LINK for TRIM Enabler 2.2 for Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard](http://nctritech.com/2019/04/23/working-download-link-for-trim-enabler-2-2-for-mac-os-x-10-6-8-snow-leopard/), did *not* work at all.